# Delete from array help

Tags: php, html, cookies

I have a cookie which stores info in an array.

This is for a classifieds website, and whenever users delete their 'ads' the cookie must also be removed of the ad which was deleted.

So I have this:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['watched_ads'])){
$expir = time()+1728000;
        $ad_arr = unserialize($_COOKIE['watched_ads']);
        foreach($ad_arr as $val){
            if($val==$id){  // $id is something like "bmw_m3_10141912"
                unset($val);
                            setcookie('watched_ads', serialize($ad_arr), $expir, '/');
            }
        }
        }
```

This doesn't work... any idea why? I think its a problem with the unset part...
Also, keep in mind if there is only one value inside the array, what will happen then?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got two bugs here: 1) you unset the `$val` instead of the array element itself. 2) You set the cookie within the loop to the unknown `$ad_arr2` array.

```
    foreach($ad_arr as $key => $val){
        if($val==$id){  // $id is something like "bmw_m3_10141912"
            unset($ad_arr[$key]);
        }
    }
    setcookie('watched_ads', serialize($ad_arr), $expir, '/');
```

Answer (score 0):

[`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) seems appropriate:

```
$array = array_filter($array, create_function('$v', 'return $v != '.$id.';'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you are using unset incorrectly.  [The manual on unset states](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php):

> If a static variable is unset() inside
>   of a function, unset() destroys the
>   variable only in the context of the
>   rest of a function. Following calls
>   will restore the previous value of a
>   variable.

[When you use 'as' you're assigning the value of that array element to a temporary variable](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).  You want to reference the original array:

```
foreach ($ad_arr as $key => $val)
...
            unset($ad_arr[$key]);
...
```

Comment: or, as of PHP 5, use a referenced value `foreach($arr as &$value)` http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: @dnagirl If you unset($value) in that case, you break the reference, but you do not remove the element from the array.  You still need to reference the array in the unset.

Comment: oops! true. I was thinking about how convenient it was for resetting (no more `array_walk()`!) and forgot the OP was about unsetting. `<blushing/>`